# Foundation Sites 6.4.3 menu-align mixin not working

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-6

I cannot make the mixin menu-align(right) or menu-align(center) to work with Foundation 6.4.3. No matter what I put in menu-align mixin, the result is always the same, the menu is always left aligned. Probably there's something I am doing wrong but I cannot figure out what it is.

Here's my HTML code and my SASS:

```css
.main-header {
  @include xy-grid;
}

.left-nav {
  @include xy-cell(auto, true, $grid-padding-gutters, padding, right left);
  background-color: blue;
}

.right-nav {
  @include xy-cell(auto, true, $grid-padding-gutters, padding, right left);
  background-color: red;
}

.main-menu {
  @include menu-base;
  @include menu-align(left);
  @include menu-direction(horizontal);
}

.language-menu {
  @include menu-base;
  @include menu-align(right);
  @include menu-direction(horizontal);
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <nav class="left-nav">
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav class="right-nav">
    <ul class="language-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[image: Menu align not working]

You can see in the screenshot the red div should have the menu items aligned to the right.

If you could point me in the right direction I will appreciate it.

Thanks Pablo Viva

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question you are trying to move the text.  You can use text-right and text-center to do this.

```
  .language-menu {
  @include menu-base;
  @include menu-align(right);
  @include menu-direction(horizontal);
  @include text-right;
  }


  .main-menu {
  @include menu-base;
  @include menu-align(left);
  @include menu-direction(horizontal);
  @include text-center;
  }
```

Comment: What im actually trying to do is to make the @include menu-align(right) mixin to work.

This mixin what does is assign some flex align properties in order to move the whole menu to the left, center or right, it is provided by the framework but somehow it doesn't work when I use it.

Comment: Did you tried  to add  `@include menu-align(right)`  mixin  in first place ?

Comment: Yes I did, I included menu-base(), menu-align(right), and menu-direction(horizontal)